# Databrick spark UDF function fails- SparkRuntimeException: [UDF_ERROR.PAYLOAD] Execution of function XXXX failed - failed to set payload

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Im using databricks notebook to process some large files, providing example code that used in notebook. This code run perfectly without fail when i used my cluster Access mode was not Shared. But now we are going for Shared access mode, this is giving me some errors.
runtime version is 13.3LTS with spark 3.4.1

```
data = [("xx",cc,"sdf"),("abcd",xx,"jkhj")]
cols = ["value","x1","x2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema="value STRING,x1 STRING,x2 STRING")

MY_udf= udf(xxx, StringType())
updated_df = df.withColumn("updated_value", MY_udf(df["VALUE"]))
display(updated_df)
```

The error i got is
**SparkRuntimeException: [UDF_ERROR.PAYLOAD] Execution of function  failed XXX  - failed to set payload**

INVALID_ARGUMENT: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1860d5f1-5b01-457c-97c7-e5955a17ca8e/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xxx.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)